# How to prevent npm from installing packages in home directory?

Tags: npm

Because sometimes with my dumb mind, I installed npm packages for a project and realized after that I am still on my home directory. Forgot to change directory.

Is there way to prevent it or will stop and show an error that I am still on my home directory?

**Edit**

I am not installing global package.

Comment: I don't think this has a technological solution, I feel it is more behavourial. Can you change your command prompt to show the current directory?

Comment: Yeah, I need to slow down a bit.

Answer (score 2):

As Burgi said on the comment, there is no solution for this.

This answer is just a workaround.

What I came up with is to add `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` to my home directory with a root permission. So that if I mistakenly install a package there, It will just give me an `EACCESS` error preventing the installation to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `package.json` file to your home dir but put a syntax error in it. Mine says "Wrong directory" which fails to parse at JSON. That seems to trip up `npm` and `yarn` before it starts installing.

Answer (score 0):

You could alias npm to a script that checks your current directory

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(pwd)" = "$HOME" ] && [ "$1" != "version" ]; then
  echo Don\'t do that here!
else
  npm $@
fi
```